# What is "requiring of the event-loop" for timers?

Tags: node.js, events, event-loop

https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timerspromisessettimeoutdelay-value-options

> ref <boolean> Set to false to indicate that the scheduled Timeout should not require the Node.js event loop to remain active. Default: true.

I guess I do not really know how event-loop works. Therefore I've no clue, how it deals with timers scheduler. Appreciate any materials to read as well as explanation of difference between (not) "referring"/requiring event-loop in Node.js for timers.

Comment: By default node's execution will keep track of the pending timeouts. This allows the script to run until completion even when the event-loop is empty. By setting the `ref` boolean to `false`, you're telling node that it can close itself even if that timeout is still pending.